# Assassin's Creed 3 Frontier Notoriety

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I have notoriety level 3 in the frontier and currently 16 jagers are chasing me throughout the frontier from valley-forge to john's town how do i reduce it??

Answer (score 0):

The way that notoriety works in the frontier is as follows:

**In most areas you are locked to one notoriety**, this means you can't gain or lose in those areas.

> In Concord and Lexington, you will be reduced to incognito mode if
>   there is someone there you need to talk to. The same happens for
>   homestead missions and huntsman missions.
>
> If the game bugs and you gain notoriety, than you can lose it by
>   moving zones or grabbing a wanted poster that spawns in Lexington
>   (Left over, I'm sure, from an earlier version before the decision to
>   force notoriety in the frontier).